# Signing a public x509 certificate in PHP

Tags: php, ssl, x509certificate

I would like to know how could I sign a file in php. I need to sign an XML file.  When I'm executing this piece of code, it gives me the following error:

> Warning: openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 35
>
> Warning: openssl_free_key() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 38

The code is this one:

```
$data->save("test.xml");

$signature;
$pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_public("./public.cer");
$path = 'test.xml';
openssl_sign($path, $signature, $pkeyid);
openssl_free_key($pkeyid);
```

Fixed:
Ok, so I had a misconception about the fact that I should sign data with a public certificate, and also I didn't load the data properly. I changed it and It worked :)
The function that I've used is this one:

$pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents('./private.key'));

Comment: There some good examples in the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php#example-967

Comment: You've got your concepts wrong. You *sign* data with a private key, you *verify* data with a public key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path "./public.cer" is most likely the error. Try to use an absolute path instead. You're second warning is telling you that $pkeyid is boolean which is exactly what openssl_pkey_get_public() returns on error.

Comment: And how should I write it, if my certificate is in C:/xampp/htdocs/test ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please check out this link to learn more about our community: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment